# BlurredGridMenu InflateException

Tags: android, blur, android-inflate

This is my code for BlurredGridMenu. But error occurs everytime I try to get the blur menu.  I can't find where the error is.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.goka.blurredgridmenu.GridMenu;
import com.goka.blurredgridmenu.GridMenuFragment;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by duSHAn maduSHAnka on 2016-01-25.
 */
public class Test3 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridMenuFragment mGridMenuFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test3);

        mGridMenuFragment = GridMenuFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.background);

        findViewById(R.id.show_menu_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                tx.replace(R.id.main_frame, mGridMenuFragment);
                tx.addToBackStack(null);
                tx.commit();
            }
        });

        setupGridMenu();

        mGridMenuFragment.setOnClickMenuListener(new GridMenuFragment.OnClickMenuListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClickMenu(GridMenu gridMenu, int position) {
                    Toast.makeText(Test3.this, "Title:" + gridMenu.getTitle() + ", Position:" + position,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
}

        private void setupGridMenu() {
            List<GridMenu> menus = new ArrayList<>();
            menus.add(new GridMenu("Home", R.drawable.n));
            menus.add(new GridMenu("Calendar", R.drawable.nn));
            menus.add(new GridMenu("Overview", R.drawable.nnn));
            menus.add(new GridMenu("Groups", R.drawable.nnnn));
            menus.add(new GridMenu("Lists", R.drawable.nnnnn));
            menus.add(new GridMenu("Profile", R.drawable.nnnnnn));

        mGridMenuFragment.setupMenu(menus);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (0 == getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
    }
}
```

Did I make any error here??

This is my XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Test3">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/show_menu_button"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Show Menu"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:alpha="0.8"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the error. LogCat

```
03-02 13:02:40.453 17063-17063/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-02 13:02:40.850 17063-17063/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using android:theme instead.
03-02 13:02:40.998 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
03-02 13:02:41.009 17063-17063/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/Atlas: Validating map...
03-02 13:02:41.190 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-02 13:02:41.191 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-02 13:02:41.207 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-02 13:02:41.266 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
03-02 13:02:41.314 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
03-02 13:02:41.334 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-02 13:02:41.334 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xef0358c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-02 13:02:45.895 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-02 13:02:45.895 17063-17083/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3f73740, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-02 13:02:47.479 17063-17063/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-02 13:02:47.484 17063-17063/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                              Process: com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat, PID: 17063
                                                                                              android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.goka.blurredgridmenu.BlurringView
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.GridMenuFragment.onCreateView(GridMenuFragment.java:39)
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.GridMenuFragment.onCreateView(GridMenuFragment.java:39) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v8/renderscript/RenderScript;
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.BlurringView.initializeRenderScript(BlurringView.java:112)
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.BlurringView.<init>(BlurringView.java:54)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.GridMenuFragment.onCreateView(GridMenuFragment.java:39) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat-3/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.BlurringView.initializeRenderScript(BlurringView.java:112) 
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.BlurringView.<init>(BlurringView.java:54) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
                                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
                                                                                                  at com.goka.blurredgridmenu.GridMenuFragment.onCreateView(GridMenuFragment.java:39) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617) 
                                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
                                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript
                                                                                                  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                                        ... 26 more
                                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**I know its too late to answer this question, but it may help others who are facing the same issue.**

The below issue, comes into the picture if you are not defining the "**renderscript**" in **build.gradle** file in the app folder of your **application module**. As, per the guidelines of Library maker.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.goka.blurredgridmenu.BlurringView
```

So, you need to **enable the renderscript**, like below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23

        renderscriptTargetApi 22  
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
}
```

**Note:**

If you are using renderscriptTargetApi as 22, then I am sorry you will going to face one issue saying....

```
Renderscript support mode is not currently supported with renderscript target 21+
```

Yep, this is a **bug** and the bug is related to renderscriptTargetApi

**How you can resolve the above issue.**

**Solution 1:**
You can define renderscriptTargetApi below 2, like:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 20
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

**Solution 2:**
The bug related to renderscriptTargetApi has been fixed in gradle-plugin 2.1.0 and Build-Tools 23.0.3. Hence you can try this too.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    }
}
```

Hope, this may help you and someone else.

Comment: thank you. but i have solved it.but thakz again for the reply.